# Best practice to work with android application and .Net web Api

Tags: android, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api, java-client

I have a .net webApi project that contains some methods.
The methods send and get complex objects.

My android application gets the objects in json format and parsing them manually.
In any changes of the objects in the WebApi project I have to change manually the android application project.

I would like to know what is the best practice to work with android application client and .Net WebApi.

There is any tool to connect between them or to auto map the objects?

Please help me
Tal

Answer (score 0):

U do use json parsing technique for parsing the json responses.its proper way of data parsing there is i think no tool for auto mapping.

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Client end you have to use [Spring RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) together with Data Transfer Objects (DTOs). You wouldn't need to manually manipulate a JSON String values. It's all about dealing with Java Objects then. You can directly pass the Objects to the RestTemplate as Entity classes and get the JSON String Auto Mapped to your DTOs.